# Sharing data between fragment and its parent activity using ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

I would like to ask if it's correct to share the same `ViewModel` between `Fragment` and its `Activity`.I have `UserDetailActivity` and `UserDetailFragment`. Can I use the same `ViewModel` to display detail data of a user in the `UserDetailActivity` and `UserDetailFragment` or is there better approach.

Comment: Just use UserDetailFragment, why do you want to use UserDetailActivity? UserdetailActivity can work as a container activity for the fragment.

Comment: In UserDetailActivity I have ViewPager with two fragments. In Activity I want display only user's profile image and name, other profile data in other fragments.

Comment: You can you the same model class, but the best approach is to only use fragments to display your UI and a container activity to hold all the fragments together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass ViewModal object from a Activity to Fragment or vice-versa by implementing Parcelable into ViewModal class and can share object with fragment setArguments() method.

Comment: ViewModel passing as arguments ???!!! Bad idea.. You should always initialize Same ViewModel in Fragment as you do in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using **MVVM** but I think its the same with **MVP**, I use the same **Presenter(ViewModel in your case)** with my **Activity** and its child **Fragment**. It make since because a **Fragment** is literally a fragment of an **Activity**. There might be some special cases where you really want to separate viewModel of **Fragment** and **Activity**, but most of the time, they share. About the initialization, dont pass your viewmodel directly, you can use dagger and inject it.